# EF DbContext.BulkInsert: Ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert

I am expiriencing weird issue with the EF extension BulkInsert (MVC5, EF6).

Here is my code structure:
My db context is inherited from IdentityDbContext (I use Owin)
Entity interface

```
 public interface IMyObject
 {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
 }
```

Base entity object

```
   public class MyObject: IMyObject
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id
        {
            get
            {
                if (_id == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    _id = Guid.NewGuid();
                }
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }
        private Guid _id;
```

Inherited entity object

```
     public class Client : MyObject
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Town{get;set;}
....
    }
```

I am trying to insert a big collection of Client objects into the database using BulkInsert:

```
     private void InsertDataToDatabase<T>(ICollection<T> dbObjects) where T : class, IMyObject
            {
        MyContext.BulkInsert<T>(dbObjects, 5000);
//fails
    }
```

However this standard insert approach works fine:

```
     private void InsertDataToDatabase<T>(ICollection<T> dbObjects) where T : class, IMyObject
                {
             foreach (var entity in dbObjects)
            {
                MyContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            }
            MyContext.SaveChanges();
            //works fine
        }
```

The exeption in BulkInsert is:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found. at
>   System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers) at System.Type.GetProperty(String name,
>   BindingFlags bindingAttr) at
>   EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Extensions.TypeExtensions.GetProperty(Type
>   type, String propertyName, Char separator) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Extensions\TypeExtensions.cs:line
>   79 at
>   EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.MapProperty(EntityMap
>   entityMap, EdmProperty edmProperty, Int32& i, String& prefix) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:line
>   488 at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappers.MapperBase.MapEntity(String
>   typeFullName, EdmType edmItem) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappers\MapperBase.cs:line
>   357 at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Mappings.DbMapping..ctor(DbContext
>   context) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Mappings\DbMapping.cs:line
>   82 at EntityFramework.MappingAPI.EfMap.Get(DbContext context) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\EfMap.cs:line
>   60 at
>   EntityFramework.MappingAPI.Extensions.MappingApiExtensions.Db(DbContext
>   ctx, Type type) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\trunk\src\EntityFramework.MappingAPI\Extensions\MappingApiExtensions.cs:line
>   51 at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at
>   EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Helpers.MappedDataReader`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   enumerable, IEfBulkInsertProvider provider) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Helpers\MappedDataReader.cs:line
>   58 at
>   EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.Run[T](IEnumerable`1
>   entities, SqlTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader.cs:line
>   22 at
>   EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase`2.Run[T](IEnumerable`1
>   entities, IDbTransaction transaction, BulkInsertOptions options) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:line
>   77 at
>   EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Providers.ProviderBase`2.Run[T](IEnumerable`1
>   entities, BulkInsertOptions options) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Providers\ProviderBase.cs:line
>   105 at
>   EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 entities, SqlBulkCopyOptions
>   sqlBulkCopyOptions, Nullable`1 batchSize) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:line
>   95 at
>   EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.BulkInsertExtension.BulkInsert[T](DbContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 entities, Nullable`1 batchSize) in
>   c:\dev\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\dev\Src\EntityFramework.BulkInsert\Extensions\BulkInsertExtension.cs:line
>   75 at
>   My.Portal.Controllers.InstallController.InsertDataToDatabase[T](ICollection`1
>   objects) in
>   C:\xxxx\Controllers\InstallController.cs:line
>   581

Please help.

Comment: is this typo: `InsertDataToDatabase<T>(ICollection<T> objects)` and inside function you use `MyContext.BulkInsert<T>(dbObjects, 5000);`, _objects_ parameter and _dbObjects_

Comment: hey, yes, objects=dbobjects. Fixed the post.

Comment: but error on _InsertDataToDatabase_ with two parameters, collection and guid, but you provide just declaration with one parameter

Comment: I am sorry, could you please be more specific? I don't get it :(

Comment: I got what you meant, I fixed it. This is not a case of the problem, unfortunatelly. Just forgot to cut out this from logs.